# Component view problem. Model method not called

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, view

Today I made my first Joomla component following their [tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component). Everything in my component was working as intended until I decided to add a second view to my component. I added a new folder in the `/views/` directory of my component and added all the necessary files : `view.html.php, index.html, tmpl/default.xml, tmpl/default.php, tmpl/index.html`.

Here is my **view.html.php**

```
class VacanciesViewSingle extends JViewLegacy
{
    var $vacancy = null;

    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $this->vacancy = $this->get('Vacancy');

        // // Check for errors.
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
        {
            JLog::add(implode('<br />', $errors), JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');

            return false;
        }

        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

As long as I understood how components in Joomla work this should call the `getVacancy()` method from my model class.

Inside my model class I have only 2 functions:
`getVacancies()` which works perfectly with my other view and `getVacancy()` which for debugging purposes return just a number:

```
public function getVacancy()
{
    return "10";
}
```

So I'm expecting my view to output "10". This is my `tmpl/default.php' file:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
?>
<?php echo $this->vacancy;?>
```

PS. Opening `/index.php?option=com_vacancies&view=single` doesn't return any errors, just my page with blank space where the component output should be...
PS2. If I change `$this->vacancy = $this->get('Vacancy');` to `$this->vacancy = "10"` in my view class I get the expected output of '10' so I suppose `getVacancy()` is not called for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you only have one model, rather than the expected one-model-per-view.

As such, it is looking for the function in a model related to your singles view, which does not exist.

Try passing a second parameter to the get function to confirm the name of the model you want to use, ie

```
$this->vacancy =$this->get('vacancy','vacancies');
```

(replacing 'vacancies' if you have called your model something else)

Further details of how the get function works are [here](https://docs.joomla.org/API15:JView/get).

Comment: So is it possible to have multiple views in a component with a single model?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to tell your other views which model to use, as per the answer above. There may be better ways (I'm wondering if a simple second model that just inherits the other one may be a tidier approach), but I tend to use JModelLegacy::getInstance to get access to a different model's functions if I need to do that.